# A single function to rule them all

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I'm learning programming with Python, and I need a function where I can send different variables to modify them, but if the variable doesn't exist, it creates one with a defined value.

Lets say I have...:

```
x = 83
y = 91
```

... And I need a function that modifies the existing variables, but if I send a variable that is not defined, then it creates it. Say I need that any variable created starts at 60. So I send the Z value to my function, and since it isn't defined, it defines `z = 60`.

My problem is I don't even know how to write said function. Is it even possible? Or do i need to have `z = 0` as a placeholder, check if it's equal to 0, and then modify it? I don't want to have variables that may not be used occupying space. I'm using Python 3.

Comment: you don't want to do that, not in the global namespace at least, use a dictionary for this with string keys and integer values

Comment: This sounds like [module `__getattr__`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/), where the name of the attribute is passed as an argument.

Comment: Every beginner wants to do this at some point, then they fail, at some point they realize that using a container (dictionary) is the key (pun intended)

Comment: If you just want to change arbitrary variables, the `=` syntax does exactly that.

Comment: Use a `defaultdict(int)`, or a `Counter`. You can wrap it in a function if you want, but that's not necessary.